# how to import file passed as command line argument in python

Tags: python

I tried to import a file var.py to openfile.py. var is passed as an argument to openfile. I am unable to figure out how to import it by reading the name from command line.

```
var = sys.argv[1]
importlib.import_module(var, package=None)
```

I tried the above code but it gave the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "true.py", line 7, in <module>
    importlib.import_module(var, package=None)
NameError: name 'importlib' is not defined
```

Comment: Shuldn't you `import` `importlib` itself?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `importlib` module.

Thats why you are getting `NameError: name 'importlib' is not defined`

do `import importlib`

**Note:**

If `imporlib` is not installed, you can install it using `easy_install`/`pip` on *nix:

`easy_install importlib`

Comment: This version of the answer is much better than the original one that simply recommended installing with `easy_install importlib` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the `importlib` module first:

```
import importlib
....
importlib.import_module(...)
```